# PredictionIO handshake_failure

Tags: predictionio

I am giving PredictionIO a test and am getting below error on pio commands build, train and deploy:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

The commands do run sucessfuly, but I am unsure if this error matters.